# Arduino Interrupt getting triggered more than once - Working with Hall Sensor for RPM

Tags: arduino, iot, arduino-uno, android-sensors, arduino-ide

I am working with an hall sensor for counting the RPM of my wheel. I am using following sensor :
[image]

My code as follows :

```
int hall_pin = 3;  // digital pin
float hall_threshold = 5.0;
float count = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(hall_pin,INPUT);// put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(hall_pin),hall_ISR,RISING);
}

void loop() {
  count = 0.0;
  float start = micros();
   
  while(1){
    
    if(count >= hall_threshold){
      break;
    } 
  }
   
  float end_time = micros();
  float time_passed = (end_time - start)/1000000.0;  // in seconds
  float rpm = (count/time_passed)*60.0;
  Serial.println(rpm);
  delay(10000);
  

}

void hall_ISR()           
{    
   count+=1.0;
}
```

I am using digital pin 3 to read from sensor and count the number of times it detects magnetic field using interrupt. Since the sensor outputs 1 on detecting, I have used  a `RISING` interrupt. Once the `count` is greater than 5 then the control comes out of the infinite loop and calculates the RPM. The problem is this interrupt is getting triggered multiple times. I have tried using  `detachInterrupt(hall_pin)` but it is not working. I also tried to decrease the sensitivity of hall sensor using the trimmer provided.

I am sure the problem is not with the sensor, it is with the interrupt, I guess. Where am I going wrong?
Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Bad idea to use a float for what is essentially an integer ranging from zero to five.  Also any variable you change in an interrupt should be `volatile` and atomic if possible.  I'd choose `uint8_t` It's atomic and fast.

Comment: Does the Hall sensor drive active high as well as pulling low? If not, then maybe use `INPUT_PULLUP` to configure the pin. I agree with Mr.Servo about not using a float just to count things (maybe use the Arduino `word`), but that shouldn't generate multiple interrupts. Do you have long wires between the sensor and the Uno - maybe they need a shielded cable?

Comment: @TomServo thank you for replying, I changed it from float to uint8_t, still no changes. The interrupt is getting triggered more than once.

Comment: @aMike thank you for replying, the sensor does drive active high and is pulling low too. And yes I have long wires between sensor and arduino uno.

Comment: @aMike Even `word` in Arduino is not atomic.  If it is used in an interrupt, it is *critical* that one observe the very specific instructions in the Atmel application notes that cover how to safely save non-atomic variables in an interrupt context.

Comment: @newbie99 You might want to scope that sensor output, or at least observe the datasheet for it.  If that's the case, you might need to determine the pin state in the interrupt so it only fires on rise (or fall).  Might also need a stronger external pullup or pulldown to sharpen the signal.  Also if using long leads, try using twisted pair to minimize problems.  You can make your own twisted pair from wire and a handheld drill in about 90 seconds.

Comment: These modules must be tuned to match your magnet and physical setup.  The potentiometer having 10 tuns, it means tuning needs to be precise, and can be a bit tricky to set properly.  Best is to use a scope, and short wires to start with.